# How to unpack a .jar file after creating one in Lieiningen?

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen, compojure

I run `lein uberjar` and I can deploy the project. The problem is that I don't know how to "undo" the .jar file and revert it back to Clojure.

I looked around but I haven't been able to find any solution. The reason I'd like to do this is because I have a project that I'm deploying to .jar. I'm not using lein server due to the issues enumerated [here](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/TUTORIAL.md#server-side-projects). I'm storing user avatars in the file system. I'm not entirely sure if my strategy is sound, so I'd like to have the flexibility to make changes.

Of course, if there is a better strategy, then I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jar files can be opened by any program that can unpack a zip file. [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29)

Comment: definitely close enough. Thanks.